# After button was pressed, get pixel properties from a picturebox only after mouse was clicked c#

Tags: c#, events, click, mouseevent, picturebox

I have the following code :

```
    private void Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Please click the object in the image ", "", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            click_the_object();
        }
    }
```

In the click_the_object() function I want to click a pixel in the picturebox and get it's color.

The function for getting the pixel properties is :

```
    private Color culoarepixel(Point point)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)pbOriginal.Image;

        return bitmap.GetPixel(point.X, point.Y);
    }
```

The problem is that I don't know how to make the click_the_object() function record only one click, the first one. I tried using eventhandlers, but it enters a loop.

Comment: Do you mean you want click_the_object() to be triggered only when the button is first clicked?

Comment: @Tijesunimi Yes, something like that. After I press the button, the messagebox appears, if I click ok, I have to perform a click in the picturebox, and record the clicked pixel's proprieties. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What should happen if the user clicks the button again without clicking on the picturebox?

Comment: I guess you should hook a method to the `Click` event of the picturebox itself instead of calling `click_the_object();`. Then, in those method, you should 1) unhook it from event 2) get location from mouseclick even args and pass it to `culoarepixel`

Comment: @Tijesunimi An alert box should appear and make the user select the object

Comment: @ArturUdod I can't do that because, after the user will select a pixel(the pixel represents the object) , I'll start processing the image, and after that it should select another pixel, and I don't know the time it takes to finish processing, and I don't want to use timers. I also tried using mouseeventargs but I can't make it work the way I want

Comment: Your scenario is: 1) user presses some button 2) message box appears 3) user clicks OK button 4) messagebox dissappears 5) user clicks the image 6) you start processing something. Is everything correct?

Comment: @ArturUdod yes that's it

Comment: @TothLudovicAndreas, then do it the way I proposed. I've added an answer with code.

Comment: @ArturUdod but now, if I want to select 2 objects using the same method, I can't do it. What should I do ?

Comment: @TothLudovicAndreas, 2 pictureboxes or 2 points on 1 picture box? I'd suggest you to ask a separate question and clarify your requirements.

Comment: @ArturUdod 2 points in one picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.myPictureBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
}

private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show(
        "Please click the object in the image ",
        "", 
        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, 
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        this.myPictureBox.MouseClick += this.myPictureBox_MouseClick;
    }
}

void myPictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.myPictureBox.MouseClick -= myPictureBox_MouseClick;
    var point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You've selected a pixel with coordinates: {0}:{1}", point.X, point.Y));
}
```