# How to select two pixels from a picturebox in c# and get their proprieties?

Tags: c#, coordinates, pixel, picturebox, mouseclick-event

In the previous question:

[After button was pressed, get pixel properties from a picturebox only after mouse was clicked c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311607/after-button-was-pressed-get-pixel-properties-from-a-picturebox-only-after-mous)

@ArturUdod gave me this answer:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.myPictureBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
}

private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show(
        "Please click the object in the image ",
        "", 
        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, 
        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, 
        MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        this.myPictureBox.MouseClick += this.myPictureBox_MouseClick;
    }
}

void myPictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.myPictureBox.MouseClick -= myPictureBox_MouseClick;
    var point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You've selected a pixel with coordinates: {0}:{1}", point.X, point.Y));
}
```

For the following scenario : 
1) user presses some button 
2) message box appears 
3) user clicks OK button 
4) messagebox dissappears 
5) user clicks the image 
6) you start processing something.

But right now I need the following scenario :
1) user presses a button 
2) message box appears 
3) user clicks OK button 
4) messagebox dissappears 
5) user clicks the image 
6) the program recors clicked pixel's coordinates 
7) messagebox appears
8) user clicks OK 
9) messagebox dissappears
10) user click the image again
11) the program recors clicked pixel's coordinates 
12)the image processing starts based on the two coordinates

The method above doesn't work for my new scenario, and I don't know how to adapt it. I also need to use the same picturebox.

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 variables for the clicked Points, just make a counter and you've done:

```
int i = 0;
Point p1, p2;
void myPictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if(i == 1) this.myPictureBox.MouseClick -= myPictureBox_MouseClick;
  var point = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
  MessageBox.Show(string.Format("You've selected a pixel with coordinates: {0}:{1}", point.X, point.Y));
  if(i == 0) p1 = point;
  else p2 = point;
  i++;
}
//then use the two points p1,p2 for further processing.
```

Note that, if you want to implement in your way (using `-=` to unregister the handler and so disable clicking on the `PictureBox`), you should notice to disable the *Start* button right after clicking it and enable it back at property time like this:

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   //all the code you already had go first...
   startButton.Enabled = false;
}
void myPictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
   //...
   if(i == 0) p1 = point;
   else { 
      p2 = point;
      startButton.Enabled = true;
   }
   i++;
}
```

Comment: And then you don't even have to += and -= the event handler anymore, just set i to zero in the button click, and `if (i > 1) return;` in the picture box click. The reason I'm suggesting this is because when you click the button twice, you also get the MouseClick event on the picture box twice - not good.

Comment: @Luaan yes, that's another solution/approach, I've just made a minimal change to the OP's code.

Comment: @Luaan the code the OP uses will allow the user to click 2 times only, after that there won't any chance for the OP to click more.

Comment: Yeah, but what happens if I click startButton 10 times, before clicking at the picture box? Unless the button is disabled after the first click, you'd get 10 MouseClick event handlers, so you'd click the picture box once, and get both of the points set in that one click (because myPictureBox_MouseClick will be called 10 times per click).

Comment: @Luaan as I said, there won't any times larger than 2, first (when `i=0`), the code runs normally, next click `i=1`, the `this.myPictureBox.MouseClick -= myPictureBox_MouseClick;` is executed and **unregisters** the handler from `myPictureBox.MouseClick`, then it still runs the remaining code and that's also the second time user clicks on the pictureBox. After that because the handler **has been unregistered**, clicking on the pictureBox won't have any code to handle.

Comment: Oh, but you can register the same event handler multiple times. .NET doesn't check if that handler is already there, it simply adds a new one. So if you do the += twice, you also have to do the -= twice. That's how events work in .NET.

Comment: @Luaan could you show me what part of code can register the handler twice? there is only 1 line to register the handler in the method `startButton_Click`, that means when user clicks on the start button, he can now click more 2 times on the picturebox. If you mean the `Start` button can be clicked twice, yes that's the OP's mistake, we just need to disable the start button after click and enable it back at proper time.

Comment: Yes, that's the line I'm talking about. If you click startButton, and then click it again (without clicking on the picture box), you're adding two event handlers. Which is why it should either be impossible to click on startButton until you're done clicking the picture box, or it shouldn't do += and -= of the event handler at all, rather than that just setting i to zero.

Comment: @Luaan yes, I agree that it should be handled, I'm going to add note about that.

Comment: @KingKing Thanx, it works ! But now I'm not able to show the messagebox twice... The message is very important, because the user is supposed to be dumb. I'm not that good at c# and now I'm trying to learn as much as I can . Anyway thanx again !